# GCD-style Singleton throws compile error... sometimes?

Tags: objective-c, singleton, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I'm implementing the textbook-singleton in Objective-C:

```
+ (instancetype) sharedSingleton
{
    id sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{            
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

...as I have been doing for a while. When changing an old `@synchronized`-syntax singleton to this kind, in an old project (open in the latest version of Xcode), I get the error:

```
Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)
```

...pointing at the allocation line. I have the exact same code in many parts of other code, built and run with the same environment, and never an issue... What's going on? Should I prepend the `__block` qualifier and be done with it, or is there more than meets the eye here?

The only thing I can think of is, this old project I'm modernising right now has **NOT** been transitioned to ARC... (yet)

Comment: Missing `static`? As in: `static id sharedInstance = nil;`

Comment: And, I'd replace `instancetype` with the actual instance type or with `id`.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist you're absolutely right, I just realised I was missing the `static`... I need sleep! Without it, the variable becomes `automatic` and hence deallocated as soon as the method returns. That's why I need to make it __block! Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Desdenova No, I believe `instancetype` is t least OK in this case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `static` on the `sharedInstance` variable. That line should be

```
static id sharedInstance = nil;
```

Colin Wheelas has [a good and short article about how to create singeltons using dispatch_once](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.se/2011/04/singletons-your-doing-them-wrong.html).